# Printing tuples in a loop

Tags: python, tuples

When I print the range of my tuple it prints the first line and then goes through all 13 lines and keeps adding them to my tuple. This is what I want my program to do but I'm looking to just print the last tuple that has all the information in it not all of the ones which get added up...

```
for i in range(1,13):
    tuple_list.append((line_list[i],year,header[i]))
    print(tuple_list)
```

For example if the tuples were: `[1] [1,2] [1,2,3] [1,2,3,4]` I only want to print the `[1,2,3,4]` tuple not the earlier ones. Thanks

Comment: `print(tuple_list[-1])`

Comment: [you may say thanks in the form of accept.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

For getting the last element, you need to specify `-1` as index number.

```
for i in range(1,13):
    tuple_list.append((line_list[i],year,header[i]))
print(tuple_list[-1])
```